# How can I add automatic marking to my text redactor in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a function, which will help me redacting game scripts. For example, I need to mark tags (e.g. "<p>", "<b>" etc.). I create a button, which calls a `Mark` function, and that `Mark` function calls other functions, e.g. `person`. But everything I tried didn't work for me. What should I do?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog   #модуль filedialog для диалогов открытия/закрытия файла

def Mark():
    person.start()

def person():
    personlabel = Label(text="<p>", bg="red")
    text.window_create(INSERT, window=personlabel)

def Quit(ev):
    global root
    root.destroy()
    
def LoadFile(ev):
    ftypes = [('Все файлы', '*'), ('txt файлы', '*.txt'), ('Файлы Python', '*.py'), ('Файлы html', '*.html')] # Фильтр файлов
    fn = tkinter.filedialog.Open(root, filetypes = ftypes).show()
    
    if fn == '':
        return
    textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')    # Очищаем окно редактирования
    textbox.insert('1.0', open(fn).read())   # Вставляем текст в окно редактирования
     
    global cur_path
    cur_path = fn # Храним путь к открытому файлу
   
def SaveFile(ev):
    fn = tkinter.filedialog.SaveAs(root, filetypes = [('Все файлы', '*'), ('txt файлы', '*.txt'), ('Файлы Python', '*.py'), ('Файлы html', '*.html')]).show()
    if fn == '':
        return
    open(fn, 'wt').write(textbox.get('1.0', 'end'))

root = Tk()   # объект окна верхнего уровня создается от класса Tk модуля tkinter. 
#Переменную, связываемую с объектом, часто называют root (корень)
    
    
root.title(u'AA1 scripts redactor')


panelFrame = Frame(root, height = 60, bg = 'gray')
textFrame = Frame(root, height = 340, width = 600)

panelFrame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')   #упакуем с привязкой к верху
textFrame.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'both', expand = 1)  

textbox = Text(textFrame, font='Arial 14', wrap='word')  #перенос по словам метод wrap
scrollbar = Scrollbar(textFrame)

scrollbar['command'] = textbox.yview
textbox['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

textbox.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', expand = 1)  #текстбокс слева
scrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')    #расположим скролбар (лифт) справа

loadBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Load')
saveBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Save')
markBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Mark')
quitBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Quit', bg='#A9A9A9',fg='#FF0000')

markBtn.bind("<Button-1>", Mark)
loadBtn.bind("<Button-1>", LoadFile)
saveBtn.bind("<Button-1>", SaveFile)
quitBtn.bind("<Button-1>", Quit)

loadBtn.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 130, height = 40)
saveBtn.place(x = 150, y = 10, width = 130, height = 40)
markBtn.place(x = 290, y = 10, width = 100, height = 40)
quitBtn.place(x = 430, y = 10, width = 100, height = 40)

root.mainloop()
```

UPD: Python everytime gives me an error `"TypeError:` [function]`() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"`.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of things.

The function `Mark()` is called by a `bind` method which also sends an argument. As in the other functions called by bind you can simply specify a parameter in the function definition. Also: calling a function is done by ending the function name with parenthesis.

```
def Mark(ev):  # supply one parameter
    person()   # call function "person"
```

The `person()` function tries to create a window in text, but the text widget is called `textbox`

```
def person():
    personlabel = Label(text="<p>", bg="red")
    textbox.window_create(INSERT, window=personlabel)  # text widget
```

**Addition**

When you get: `TypeError: Person() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` you can always check what is sent to the function by accepting the argument and then printing it.

```
def person(arg):
    print(f'Function argument: {arg}')
    ... rest of the function code
```

If you don't use any argument you can just accept anything sent to the function and then never look at it:

```
def person(*args, **kwargs):
    ... rest of the function code
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Person() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: i.e., it still doesn't work

Comment: From the error it looks like the function `person()` still does not accept arguments. Or maybe you have two versions, one of which begins with an upper case "P" instead of a lower case "p". Otherwise I have given examples in my answer of how to investigate the passed argument.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I fixed this error, but the code isn't working as I thought it would work. It's not marking p's in the text, it creates a new box with <p> inside. So it's still not doing what it should.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear over what you are trying to achieve, but do have a look at a couple of references which explains how the text widget works: [effbot:The Tkinter Text Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20200715112856/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) and [TkDocs Tutorial - Text](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html)